# How to proceed 2 executions in 1 step in hive?

Tags: hive

I am wondering if there is a way to proceed 2 exectuions in 1 step in hive.
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
;
```

Do this in one window, and do not have to open 2 hive windows to execute each line separetly.

Can it be done on HUE?

Answer (score 2):

You can use HiveCLI Tool to run HiveQL with a given sql file.

> $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -f /home/my/hive-script.sql

Please see official document: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli

What you need to do is to

1. Put your HiveQLs in a file as below
   `SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
   SELECT * FROM TABLE2;`
2. Use HiveCLI and run with above file

Comment: Is it possible to do this using HUE?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can execute multiple HQL's using Hue as long as each individual HQL is separated by a semi colon (;)

Comment: Looks like it does not work somehow on mine Hue.. Probably I have mb older version or something

Answer (score 1):

You can separate each query with a semi colon (;)

```
select column1 from table1;
select column2 from table2;
```

This command can be executed from command line via inline queries or a file. Usage of Hive CLI is not recommended. You must use beeline to execute queries configured via hive server 2 so that all/any underlying security control measures are honored.

you may invoke beeline with the command:

```
beeline
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this using HUE?